# Not able to run a simple GET method XHR/AJAX javascript program

Tags: javascript

```
    document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click",loadData);

    function loadData(){
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    console.log("READYSTAT",xhr.readyState)

    xhr.open("GET","trial.txt", true)

    xhr.onload = function(){
        if(this.status === 200){
            console.log(this.responseText)
        }
    }
```

This is the error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'file:///C:/Users/kenne/OneDrive/Desktop/javascript/trial.txt' from
>   origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests
>   are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
>   chrome-extension, https.

```
    xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: The error message is quite self-explanatory: you cannot use `XMLHttpRequest` or (`fetch`) when you open a `*.html` file from-disk. You will need to use a local webserver.

Answer (score 0):

`XMLHttpRequest` (XHR) is an API in the form of an object whose methods transfer data between a web browser and a web server. [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest)

`XMLHttpRequest` (XHR) objects are used to interact with servers. [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

from this

```
file:///C:/Users/kenne/OneDrive/Desktop/javascript/trial.txt
```

I am pretty sure that the URL in your browser is something like this
`file:///C:/Users/kenne/OneDrive/Desktop/javascript/index.html`

So the requested URL `trial.txt` will request to `file:///C:/Users/kenne/OneDrive/Desktop/javascript/trial.txt`, obviously, there is no server here

Run a local HTTP server using python

```bash
$ python -m http.server
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 (http://0.0.0.0:8000/) ...
```

Comment: Thank u for your answers....so, what should be the correct code?

Comment: @KennethSolomon There is no "correct code" - you need to run your web-page from a `localhost` webserver, not from disk.

Comment: @Dai...thanks buddy...i m a beginner.....Please tell me how to run my web-page forma localhost web-server...

Comment: You can create a local server by installing nginx or apache ...